# fetching a json from bandcamp api

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

sorry if thats been asked earlier, i tried to find but dint get through
to start: http://bandcamp.com/developer

i am trying to fetch the bandID of an artist

```
var my_url = 'http://api.bandcamp.com/api/band/3/search?key=snaefellsjokull&name=metallica';

$.ajax({
                'url' : my_url,
                'type':"GET",
                success: function(res){
                    var bandId = res.result[0].bandId;
                    console.log(bandId);
                }
});
```

but i am always getting a 405 error that this method is not allowed.

I tried these as well:

```
$.getJSON(my_url, function(res){
                    var bandId = res.result[0].bandId;
                    findDisco(bandId);
                })
```

and

```
 var abc= $.parsejson(my_url);
 abc.res.result[0].bandId;
```

if u execute the url in navigation bar, it fetches the json .. and i verified it with json lint .. i think i am doing a very silly mistake .. can someone help?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: You cannot fetch data from a different domain like that. You have to use JSONP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP (server needs to support this, which it seems it does).

Comment: ohh i tried that first, forgot to mention it , i think the server doesnt support it. is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use JSONP (because you are fetching from a different domain, as I explained in my comment), which is supported:

> **Parameters.** There are three parameters that apply to every function call:
>
> **key** – Your developer key must be included in every call.
>      **debug** – Optional parameter that instructs the API to return the text of the JSON blob in a more human-readable format, including spaces and newlines.
>      **callback** – If you include this parameter the response will use the JSONP format with the specified callback function name.

Second, you need to access the right fields. E.g. it is `res.results` instead of `res.result` and `band_id` instead of `bandId`:

> **Response**
>
> For a single band id the response is a hash with the following items. For batch mode, the response is a hash mapping the requested band ids to their blobs of info.
>
> **band_id** – the numeric id of the band.
>      **name** – the band’s name. This may not be unique, especially if the band is shy about their name.
>      **subdomain** – the band’s subdomain. This will be unique across all the bands.
>      **url** – the band’s home page.
>      **offsite**_url – the band’s alternate home page, not on Bandcamp.

All taken from the [documentation you linked to](http://bandcamp.com/developer).

This works:

```
var my_url = 'http://api.bandcamp.com/api/band/3/search?key=snaefellsjokull&name=metallica&callback=?';

$.ajax({
    'url': my_url,
    'type': "GET",
    'dataType': 'jsonp',
    success: function(res) {
        var bandId = res.results[0].band_id;
        console.log(bandId);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks yeah it works ... i did not put the callback=? , seems like i need more documentation from jquery.ajax .. thanks a lot!!

Comment: @fatSlave: You're welcome. You need the parameter, otherwise the server does not know that it has to serve JSONP.

Comment: @FelixKling what do you think about this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853231/how-to-get-correct-response-from-bandcamp-api